# Best way to merge in list<object> where object contains list of values

Tags: c#, list, linq, generic-list

I have an `IList<Row>` where `Row` contains a list of Cells `IList<Cell>`. These cells have a `ToString`, `ToDouble` etc.

I want to loop through this list of rows and check if there are rows with  the same value for `cell[index]`. Let's say for cell 3.
If there are rows with the same value, I should merge these rows into one row. It is certain that all cells are - in case of the same key - the same except for the cell with an amount, let's say that this is cell 4. So this should be merged (so 1 deleted) with the only difference that the value is the sum of both.

I have tried to create a `Dictionary<string, double>`. I looped through all rows, check whether map contains key, if not -> merge (also did this with an extension method Merge, but the same idea).
After this loopthrough, I created a new list, placed the dictionary in there and looped through the old list for the other information.

Well I think that my way is way too long, that there should be a way to do this much easier, maybe by LINQ or whatsoever. Any idea's on how to do this properly? Or do you guys think that my approach isn't that bad?

Comment: please add some code to the post. Sounds like something that can be achieved using LINQ GroupBy

Comment: @Matt.G yes I thought so.. Wdym code? It's not really relevant imo. the text says it all right Oo

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var mergedRows = rows.GroupBy(x => x.Cells[0].Value.ToString())
            .Select(x => new Row() { Cells = new List<Cell>
                                                {
                                                   new Cell() { Value = x.Key },
                                                   new Cell() { Value = x.Sum(y => int.Parse(y.Cells[1].Value.ToString())) }
                                                }
                                   });
```